# Bleak integration in PyQT5

Tags: python, pyqt5, bluetooth-lowenergy

- bleak version: 0.14.2
- Python version: 3.8.1rc1
- Operating System: Windows 10 Enterprise LTBS
- BlueZ version (`bluetoothctl -v`) in case of Linux: None

#### Description

I'm coding a desktop app for Windows to manage intertial sensors. The app is been developed in PyQT5 building a GUI for connect to sensor by bleak and sending/receiving by uart. So, I want to integrate in a GUI in Pyqt the bleak library that uses asyncio.

I can scan devices without problem. But when I want to connect to sensor and run infinite loop reading and writing bytes like https://github.com/hbldh/bleak/blob/develop/examples/uart_service.py

the GUI is frozen and not responding. I have used asyncio routines in differente ways in order to run the process in backgroud with no success.

Anybody has experience integrating bleak in Pyqt5/Pyside2.

#### What I Did

I have a main.py file with the UI and two simple modules for scan and connecting. I can connect it and receive data but after seconds GUI does not respond. I have seen some libraries like qtrio for this purposes but I want to know if Pyqt and bleak has a good integration.

Thanks for your support.

Here my starter code in the UI

```
import asyncio
import qasync
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTextEdit, QPushButton, QListWidgetItem, QListWidget, QApplication
from PyQt5 import QtBluetooth, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread
from PyQt5.QtBluetooth import QBluetoothAddress
import sys
from bleak import discover
from ble import discover
from ble import connect
from qasync import QEventLoop

#main.py
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('mainwindow.ui', self)
        self.streamtext = self.findChild(QTextEdit, "streamtext")
        self.listDevicesText = self.findChild(QListWidget, "addressList")
        self.scanButton = self.findChild(QPushButton, "scanButton")
        self.connectButton = self.findChild(QPushButton,"connectButton")
        self.exitButton = self.findChild(QPushButton,"exitButton")
        self.exitButton.clicked.connect(self.quit)
        self.scanButton.clicked.connect(self.discover_devices)
        self.connectButton.clicked.connect(self.connect_devices)
        self.show()

    def discover_devices(self):
        list = {}
        list = asyncio.run(discover.main(),debug=True)
        self.listDevicesText.addItem(list.get("Sensor1"))

    def connect_devices(self):
        # Get the first line is macaddress
        asyncio.run(connect.run(self.listDevicesText.item(0).text()))


    def quit(self):
        sys.exit(0)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    try:
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        window = MainWindow()
        app.exec()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

#ble/connect.py
async def run(macaddress):
   
    async with BleakClient(macaddress, disconnected_callback=handle_disconnect) as client:
        
        while True:
          # here is reading/writing gatt char process

#ble/discover.py
import asyncio
from bleak import BleakScanner

async def main():
    devicelist = {}
    devices = await BleakScanner.discover()
    for d in devices:
        devicelist.update({d.name:d.address})
    return devicelist
```

Answer (score 1):

Programming is not putting pieces of code together and putting them together as they are. The idea is to understand how each element works and analyze how they can coexist and cooperate. In this case it is better to create a QObject that allows to handle bleak and use qasync so that Qt can coexist with asyncio as shown below:

```py
import asyncio
from dataclasses import dataclass
from functools import cached_property
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QComboBox,
    QLineEdit,
    QMainWindow,
    QPlainTextEdit,
    QPushButton,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QWidget,
)

import qasync

from bleak import BleakScanner, BleakClient
from bleak.backends.device import BLEDevice

UART_SERVICE_UUID = "6E400001-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E"
UART_RX_CHAR_UUID = "6E400002-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E"
UART_TX_CHAR_UUID = "6E400003-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E"

UART_SAFE_SIZE = 20


@dataclass
class QBleakClient(QObject):
    device: BLEDevice

    messageChanged = pyqtSignal(bytes)

    def __post_init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    @cached_property
    def client(self) -> BleakClient:
        return BleakClient(self.device, disconnected_callback=self._handle_disconnect)

    async def start(self):
        await self.client.connect()
        await self.client.start_notify(UART_TX_CHAR_UUID, self._handle_read)

    async def stop(self):
        await self.client.disconnect()

    async def write(self, data):
        await self.client.write_gatt_char(UART_RX_CHAR_UUID, data)
        print("sent:", data)

    def _handle_disconnect(self) -> None:
        print("Device was disconnected, goodbye.")
        # cancelling all tasks effectively ends the program
        for task in asyncio.all_tasks():
            task.cancel()

    def _handle_read(self, _: int, data: bytearray) -> None:
        print("received:", data)
        self.messageChanged.emit(data)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(640, 480)

        self._client = None

        scan_button = QPushButton("Scan Devices")
        self.devices_combobox = QComboBox()
        connect_button = QPushButton("Connect")
        self.message_lineedit = QLineEdit()
        send_button = QPushButton("Send Message")
        self.log_edit = QPlainTextEdit()

        central_widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        lay = QVBoxLayout(central_widget)
        lay.addWidget(scan_button)
        lay.addWidget(self.devices_combobox)
        lay.addWidget(connect_button)
        lay.addWidget(self.message_lineedit)
        lay.addWidget(send_button)
        lay.addWidget(self.log_edit)

        scan_button.clicked.connect(self.handle_scan)
        connect_button.clicked.connect(self.handle_connect)
        send_button.clicked.connect(self.handle_send)

    @cached_property
    def devices(self):
        return list()

    @property
    def current_client(self):
        return self._client

    async def build_client(self, device):
        if self._client is not None:
            await self._client.stop()
        self._client = QBleakClient(device)
        self._client.messageChanged.connect(self.handle_message_changed)
        await self._client.start()

    @qasync.asyncSlot()
    async def handle_connect(self):
        self.log_edit.appendPlainText("try connect")
        device = self.devices_combobox.currentData()
        if isinstance(device, BLEDevice):
            await self.build_client(device)
            self.log_edit.appendPlainText("connected")

    @qasync.asyncSlot()
    async def handle_scan(self):
        self.log_edit.appendPlainText("Started scanner")
        self.devices.clear()
        devices = await BleakScanner.discover()
        self.devices.extend(devices)
        self.devices_combobox.clear()
        for i, device in enumerate(self.devices):
            self.devices_combobox.insertItem(i, device.name, device)
        self.log_edit.appendPlainText("Finish scanner")

    def handle_message_changed(self, message):
        self.log_edit.appendPlainText(f"msg: {message.decode()}")
        
    @qasync.asyncSlot()
    async def handle_send(self):
        if self.current_client is None:
            return
        message = self.message_lineedit.text()
        if message:
            await self.current_client.write(message.encode())

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    loop = qasync.QEventLoop(app)
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    with loop:
        loop.run_forever()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Hi, Eyllanesc: First of all, thanks for your help. The code of your "main" method was used in other version of this code in order of using qasync but GUI was frozen. I have not a lot of examples of qasync. Please, could you provide me any book for use qasync and qt? There's very poor doc of Pyqt Asynchronous.  I consider using QObject is a very useful idea. And I have another question if you were kind for answer it. It is better coding GUI desktop asynchronous apps with bleak in another GUI framework instead of PyQT? Maybe WPF/C# or QBluetooth/Pyqt. I don't know if qasync is gonna work always

Comment: @HeavyMetalDrummer There is no book about qasync, it's a simple library, if you know enough about asyncio and PyQt then you shouldn't have problems with qasync, it seems that's not the case. If you are going to use bleak and Qt then qasync is the best option, another interesting option is QBluetooth (I don't know how much support and how advanced it is), if you are going to use other technologies then I reserve my opinion since I don't know them.

Comment: I think would be a better option using QBluetooth and QThread instead of bleak, and asyncio. But, anyway, Thanks for your help.