Using Bleak with threading in a PyQt/PySide application
I have a PyQt/PySide application where I use threads to process commands from a queue. In one thread, I need to use Bleak to work with BLE devices. Bleak is based on asyncio, and I am having trouble integrating these asynchronous functions into a synchronous thread. Here is a sample of my code:
import os
from pathlib import Path
import sys

from PySide6.QtCore import QObject, Slot, Signal
from PySide6.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication 

from workerCore import CoreWorker
from queue import Queue
from threading import Thread

import queueCmds  as qc

class AppWindow(QObject):
    sigPairingPopUp = Signal()    

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(None)
        self.queueCore = Queue()
        self.workerCore = CoreWorker(self)
        x = Thread(target=self.workerCore.run)
        x.start()   

    @Slot()
    def scanBLE(self):
        sd = qc.QueueData()
        sd.cmd = qc.CoreQC.SCAN_BLE
        self.queueCore.put(sd)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main = QApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    appWin = AppWindow()
    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("backend", appWin)
    engine.load(os.fspath(Path(__file__).resolve().parent / "qml/main.qml"))
    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)
    sys.exit(main.exec())

workerCore.py
import queueCmds  as qc
from threading import Thread
import asyncio
from bleak import BleakScanner, BleakClient

CHARACTERISTIC_UUID = "...."

class CoreWorker(Thread):
    def __init__(self, app, parent=None):
        super(CoreWorker, self).__init__(parent)
        self.app = app

    def run(self):
        while True:
            rxd = self.app.queueCore.get()
            if rxd.cmd == qc.CoreQC.SCAN_BLE:
                asyncio.run(self.scan_devices())

    async def scan_devices(self):
        devices = await BleakScanner.discover()
        for i, device in enumerate(devices):
            print(f"{i}: {device.name} ({device.address})")
        return devices

    async def connect_and_read(self, device_address):
        async with BleakClient(device_address) as client:
            print(f"Connected to {device_address}")
            value = await client.read_gatt_char(CHARACTERISTIC_UUID)
            print(f"Read value: {value}")

Problem:
How can I correctly integrate asynchronous Bleak functions into a synchronous thread?
At a minimum, it seems strange to combine asyncio with threading. Either way, my call to scan_devices is not working. What is the best way to solve this?
Thank you!

I don't use async, so I can't really help on that; but, what is the point of creating a Thread subclass if you then run its loop from another Thread object? Just call its start().

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71268254/bleak-integration-in-pyqt5/71269542#71269542
